# Update Shopify product cost and price using Ruby

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am using Shopify's `shopify_api` gem in Ruby.

I need to update each products cost and price from an external source.

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => limit})

products.each do |product|
        #product.variants.first.price == price
    end
end
```

Is this the correct way to update a products price?

Do I need to do `product.variants.first.save` after I have done `product.variants.first.price == price` or is that done automatically?

How can I update the products cost (`product.variants.first.cost` doesn't seem to exist)?

Comment: Tip: It's been ages since Ruby 1.9 came on the scene and introduced the `params: { ... }` hash notation. The `=>` Ruby 1.8 style is no longer necessary as 1.8 is extinct.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update product variant, I think calling the `save` method is necessary

```
variant = product.variants.first
variant.price = new_price
variant.save
```

`product cost` mentioned is `order`? You should use `ShopifyAPI::Order` ( check this [sample](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/tree/261cfe7b373786ea0f7cb3e90de694f99d419d96/test)  and the [api](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/object/order) )

If you need other attribute for product, check out the `metafields` using `ShopifyAPI::Metafield`

FYI, `Order` has `line_items` property and we also have `ShopifyAPI:LineItem` if u find it helpful

Comment: Do you mean `product.save` or `variant.save`? I need to update each products cost (it's displayed as "Cost per item" in each product in the App).

Comment: do u want to add a new attribute to product? u can use `metafield`

Comment: @user11736353 it depends. If you show `product variant price` on your app, it will be `variant.save`, if u use `product.price` to show on ur app, it will be `product.price = new_price`, `product.save`

Comment: I am talking about the Shopify iOS App.

Comment: So I think u need to save product’s variant price as in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can still update product (variant) prices like that. You will likely have to first loop through the product variants, and for each one you get an inventory_item_id. You use that to get the inventory item details. With the inventory item details, you can set the price and cost price, and SKU.

It used to be so much simpler! Another option for you is to use a mutation on the variant, and set prices with the GraphQL API. In either case, you are forced to update using the inventory item attributes and not variant price.

Comment: The price is not available using https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/inventoryitem.

Comment: Even easier then! Just use the old variant.price and be done. Change all variant prices and make one API to save the product for speed. I was confused thinking you wanted access to the cost prices, which are different.